# Dealing with Precision Issues in FindRoot for Complex Equations

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, physics

I'm currently working on a Mathematica code that involves using the FindRoot function to find the poles of the scattering matrix in an one dimentional potetial well and for that, I need to find the roots of a specific T function that shows up on the scattering matrix. However, I'm running into precision-related errors and struggling to find a solution that works effectively.

My code involves iterating through a range of variables u and n, and for each combination of these variables, I'm using FindRoot to solve an equation involving complex expressions. Here's my code:

```
T[a_, u_, k_] = (k Sqrt[k^2 + 2 u])/(
  k Sqrt[k^2 + 2 u] Cos[2 a Sqrt[k^2 + 2 u]] - 
   I (k^2 + u) Sin[2 a Sqrt[k^2 + 2 u]]);

\[Gamma]Min = 2.8; 
\[Gamma]Max = 5.2;
nMin = -6;
nMax = 6;

poleum1 = Table[
    FindRoot[
      Denominator[T[1, u, k]] /. Sqrt[k^2] -> k /. k -> I k, {k, n}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 10][[1, 2]]
   , {u, \[Gamma]Min, \[Gamma]Max, 0.01}, {n, nMin, nMax, 0.1}
];
```

Unfortunately, increasing the WorkingPrecision value to even 100 hasn't resolved the issues. The specific error message I'm encountering is:

```
FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function (I k Sqrt[5.6 -k^2] Cos[2 Sqrt[5.6 -Power[<<2>>]]]-I (2.8 -k^2) Sin[2 Sqrt[5.6 -Power[<<2>>]]]) is less than WorkingPrecision (10.`).
```

Any guidance or suggestions on how to deal with these precision issues would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Any constant containing a decimal point has a fixed small precision and can't be changed. So change each of your constants containing a decimal point into an exact rational. That lets `WorkingPrecision` and `FindRoot` make those constants any precision it needs. Even after this there are a stream of warnings, likely because of your denominator, but this is a little closer to what you need.

Comment: In general $k \rightarrow \pm \sqrt{2u}$ is a root for `Denominator[T[1, u, k]] /. Sqrt[k^2] -> k /. k -> I k`. This is always less than 6 and greater than -6 also for the given values of `u`. These two are not necessarily the only roots for each value of `u` however.